# How can I update a time interval 10 seconds greater than the previous record in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried this query but it didn't work:

```
UPDATE phonebooks SET created_at = DATE_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL 10 second)
```

My current records are like this :

| ID | DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-03-24 10:30:34 |
| 2 | 2022-03-24 10:30:34 |
| 3 | 2022-03-24 10:30:34 |
| 4 | 2022-03-24 10:30:34 |
| 5 | 2022-03-24 10:30:34 |
| 6 | 2022-03-24 10:30:34 |
| 7 | 2022-03-24 10:30:34 |

I want to get these records like this :

| ID | DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-03-24 10:30:44 |
| 2 | 2022-03-24 10:30:54 |
| 3 | 2022-03-24 10:31:04 |
| 4 | 2022-03-24 10:31:14 |
| 5 | 2022-03-24 10:31:24 |
| 6 | 2022-03-24 10:31:34 |
| 7 | 2022-03-24 10:31:44 |

Comment: *didn‘t work* is not an error description. Can you explain what is not working?

Comment: Hello, @Jens.
Thanks for the reply, you can check the answers for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are just adding 10 seconds to each row, but you need something that would increase your interval depending of the row you are updating. Based on your example, you could use the ID as a multiplier.

```
UPDATE phonebooks SET created_at = DATE_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL 10 * id second)
```

This won't work exactly as specified if you have gaps in your IDs.

Comment: Thanks, @Hendrik.
Appreciate you for the shortest query.

Comment: Super Query, Work like charm... Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

A dynamic solution for an unknown position in the table. will use user defined variables.

The starting point of  the time is determined by the UPDATE WHERE clause

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `ID` INTEGER,
>   `DATE` VARCHAR(19)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`ID`, `DATE`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '2022-03-24 10:30:34'),
>   ('2', '2022-03-24 10:30:34'),
>   ('3', '2022-03-24 10:30:34'),
>   ('4', '2022-03-24 10:30:34'),
>   ('5', '2022-03-24 10:30:34'),
>   ('6', '2022-03-24 10:30:34'),
>   ('7', '2022-03-24 10:30:34');
> ```

> ```
> SET @date = ''
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE table1 SET `DATE` = IF(@date = '', @date := DATE_ADD(`DATE`, INTERVAL 10 second), @date := DATE_ADD(@date, INTERVAL 10 second) )
> WHERE `DATE` >= '2022-03-24 10:30:34'
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table1
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | DATE               
> -: | :------------------
>  1 | 2022-03-24 10:30:44
>  2 | 2022-03-24 10:30:54
>  3 | 2022-03-24 10:31:04
>  4 | 2022-03-24 10:31:14
>  5 | 2022-03-24 10:31:24
>  6 | 2022-03-24 10:31:34
>  7 | 2022-03-24 10:31:44
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=42cde001aa59b009a5dd11b3c51a3d5b)*

Comment: Thanks, @nbk. It's worked.
Appreciating you for getting me a brief solution.